# Does "insert" in SQLite return SQLITE_OK or SQLITE_DONE?

Tags: sqlite

What does statement "insert" in SQLite return in case of success?

I always believed that it should be SQLITE_DONE, but recently in my logs I found out the following string:

```
sqlite3_step error: 'not an error'
```

And here is the code that logs the mentioned string:

```
prepareStatement(addTranslationStmt2, "INSERT INTO translations(lang1_wordid, lang2_wordid) VALUES(?, ?)");
if (!addTranslationStmt2) return -2;

sqlite3_bind_int(addTranslationStmt2, 1, word_id);
sqlite3_bind_int(addTranslationStmt2, 2, translation_id);

if(sqlite3_step(addTranslationStmt2) != SQLITE_DONE)
{
    NSLog(@"sqlite3_step error: '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_reset(addTranslationStmt2);
    return -1;
}

sqlite3_reset(addTranslationStmt2);
```

I am wondering, why does it work in most cases.
Should I change SQLITE_DONE in my code to SQLITE_OK?

Thanks.

Comment: When you printed the error code, what did you see?

Comment: Check http://code.google.com/p/database-adt/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQLITE_DONE

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html

You could also try printing out the error code to find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

In cases like these, I like to look at code samples.  Here are some good ones:

[http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/76/6659.aspx](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html)

The [SQLite Result Codes Reference](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/76/6659.aspx) lists SQLITE_OK as indicating a successful result.  It is also the first error code, having an error code of 0, making it the canonical result (i.e. the result I would expect on a successful operation).

You should put a breakpoint or print statement in your code to find out if it really is returning zero, and check your data to make sure you're getting the result you expect.  If that all checks out, I would change your condition to check for SQLITE_OK.

The details of the behavior of the `sqlite3_step()` interface depend on whether the statement was prepared using the newer "v2" interface `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` and `sqlite3_prepare16_v2()` or the older legacy interface `sqlite3_prepare()` and `sqlite3_prepare16().`

In the legacy interface, the return value will be either `SQLITE_BUSY, SQLITE_DONE, SQLITE_ROW, SQLITE_ERROR`, or `SQLITE_MISUSE`. With the "v2" interface, any of the other result codes or extended result codes might be returned as well.

Answer (score 1):

Switching from "Debug" configuration to "Release" resolved the issue for me.