# sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE is always false

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5

I am trying to Sign up a user in my application.
I have a view controller with `3 textfields (username, password and confirmpassword)` and a `submit` button.

The following method is called when submit button is pressed:

```
-(IBAction)addUser
{
    NSString *tempUser,*tempPass, *tempConfPass;
    tempUser = [[NSString alloc]init];
    tempPass = [[NSString alloc]init];
    tempConfPass = [[NSString alloc]init];
    tempUser = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_mUserName.text];
    tempPass = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_mPassword.text];
    tempConfPass = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_mConfPassword.text];
    signupUser = [[UseDb alloc]init];

    flagUser = [signupUser addNewUser:_mUserName.text:_mPassword.text:_mConfPassword.text];
    if(flagUser)
    {
        myAlertViewUser = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"User Added"
                                                    delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [myAlertViewUser show];
    }
    else {
       _mStatus.text = @"failed to add user";
       myAlertViewUser = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"passwords don't match"
                                delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

       [myAlertViewUser show];
    }
}
```

and this method is called by `addUser` method:

```
-(BOOL)addNewUser:(NSString *)newUser :(NSString *)newPassword :(NSString *)confirmPass
{
   NSLog(@"%@....%@...%@",newUser, newPassword, confirmPass);
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [_mDatabasePathDb UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_mDb) == SQLITE_OK && [newPassword isEqualToString:confirmPass] && ![newUser isEqualToString:@""] && ![newPassword isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        self.userName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newUser];
        self.password = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newPassword];

        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"INSERT INTO USERDETAIL VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\")",self.userName,self.password,@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"" ];

        NSLog(@"%@",insertSQL);
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(_mDb, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            return YES;
            /*    mUserName.text = @"";
             mPassword.text = @"";
             mConfPassword.text = @""; */

        }
        else {

            NSLog(@"failed to add user");
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(_mDb);
    }
}
```

In the `addNewUser` method,  `if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)` is always coming out to be `false`, statement has some value before

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(_mDb, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
```

but turns to `nil` after the above statement is executed. I don't understand why that is happening.
Please help.

Comment: Print and see what you are getting as sqlite3_step(statement)?

Comment: Remarks: You do not check the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. What *does* `sqlite3_step()` return? If it is SQLITE_ERROR, what does `sqlite3_errmsg()` tell you?

Comment: And note that your INSERT statement is prone to SQL injection (http://xkcd.com/327/). You should use the `sqlite3_bind_XXX()` functions to bind the values to the prepared statement.

Comment: NSLog(@"%d",sqlite3_step(statement)); yields 21. What does that mean?

Comment: 21 is SQLITE_MISUSE. That could mean that creating the prepared statement already failed. You should check the return value of sqlite3_prepare_v2()! If that fails, check sqlite3_errmsg()!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be an issue with the check you are doing, try SQLITE_OK. Its said here in [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) as In the legacy interface(older interface), the return value will be either **SQLITE_BUSY, SQLITE_DONE, SQLITE_ROW, SQLITE_ERROR, or SQLITE_MISUSE**. With the **"v2" interface**, any of the other result codes or extended result codes might be returned as well.

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_mDb, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
               return YES;
            }
            else 
            {
              NSLog(@"failed to add user");
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
```

you can also find a similar question and its answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053020/does-insert-in-sqlite-return-sqlite-ok-or-sqlite-done)

Insert a curly brace after the prepare statement and close it after finalize statement. As you get SQLITE_MISUSE, it can be that this routine was called inappropriately. Perhaps it was called on a prepared statement that has already been finalized or on one that had previously returned SQLITE_ERROR or SQLITE_DONE. Or it could be the case that the same database connection is being used by two or more threads at the same moment in time.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_mDb, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) comes out to be false.

Comment: check your query. I guess its not executed properly

Comment: insert query is working properly. I checked using SQLite manager.

Comment: You said you got 21 as output ie;SQLITE_MISUSE. Check if you have closed the db you opened elsewhere before you opened the second time.

Comment: I can't find any open connections to the db. I've closed them everywhere.

Comment: @StudentX: What is the return value of sqlite3_prepare_v2()?

Comment: Are you creating this database in code or using one from your main bundle?  I am guessing it is the latter and that you didn't actually copy it to your documents directory.

Comment: @borrrden: But in that case sqlite3_open() would fail already, don't you think so?

Comment: @MartinR Absolutely not, that is where you are wrong.  If it doesn't exist, it will create a **new empty database**

Comment: @borrrden: OK, I see what you mean. But it would definitely help if the OP would check and report *all* return values (including sqlite3_prepare_v2), together with the sqlite3_errmsg() in the case of an SQLITE_ERROR. He did not provide that information until now, so we can only guess about the problem.

Comment: The problem was resolved after I used a common object(shared instance)  of UseDb instead of creating new ones for every method. Thanks for your help guys..