# Sqlite DB Locked

Tags: objective-c, iphone, sqlite

```
-(void)insertQuery:(NSString *)query{
    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
    // Create a sqlite object.
    sqlite3 *database;
    // Set the database file path.
    NSString *databasePath = [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];

    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        //*************** insert value in database******************************\\

        const char *sql = [query UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL);
        if(sqlite3_step(selectstmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"insert successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"insert not successfully");
            NSLog(@"DB Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Using above code trying to fire insert query but sometime it works and most of the time i get DB locked error.

For helping hands Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see a SQL statement.

Comment: This error happens when you forgot to clean up some statement or connection. This code looks OK; the error is somewhere else.

Comment: It's not really OK.  Opening the database every time a statement is executed is very expensive.  It's also likely the root-cause of this issue as the OP is not managing the connections properly.

Comment: @trojanfoe hey i mean to say any of the insert statement

Comment: @trojanfoe so what can be the other approaches if u can guide me some

Comment: Using a singleton pattern for getting the one-and-only database connection.  You also need the connection to be closed, for when the app goes into the background.

Comment: @trojanfoe but DB operations executes within a second and so i close the DB after every operations

Comment: yes its just a simple insert statement. It just effects only 10 column per request

Comment: Within a second **what**?  Within a second thread?  A second as in time?

Comment: as per my knowledge DB query executes in milliseconds

Comment: Opening and closing database connections does not take milliseconds, however, and it's simply a waste of processing time to do so.

Comment: so how can i handle lockings

Answer (score 2):

- http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/11/04/simple-sqlite-database-interaction-using-fmdb/

Use this link and manage your Database with this using FMDB. I also faced this problem 5 months back and used this and my problem resolved 100%.

- https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Comment: pls accept my answer if yor problem is resolved @vje1998

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the connection properly.

```
if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    //*************** insert value in database******************************\\

    const char *sql = [query UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL);
    if(sqlite3_step(selectstmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"insert successfully");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"insert not successfully");
        NSLog(@"DB Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: even after doing the same thing same scenario persist

Answer (score 0):

Database lock usually happens when you are writing something to database or you have left some other connection open. Check you other code for lose connections.

Try to check for SQLITE_OK for sqlite3_prepare_v2 because database may be busy and may return SQLITE_BUSY for step statement. Further explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891190/sqlite3-stepstatement-sqlite-done-is-always-false). Try following code:

```
if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    //*************** insert value in database******************************\\

    const char *sql = [query UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
      if(sqlite3_step(selectstmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
      {
          NSLog(@"insert successfully");
      }
      else
      {
          NSLog(@"insert not successfully");
          NSLog(@"DB Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
      }
      sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```