# How to rename column name in sqlite not works in objective c

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I want to rename a column name.

```
    NSString *status;
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    NSString *alterTable = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"ALTER TABLE C RENAME COLUMN X TO Y"];
    const char *update_stmt = [alterTable UTF8String];

    sqlite3_prepare_v2([DBConnection dataBase], update_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        status = @"Success";
    else
        status = @"Failed";
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

the query status is failed.
I use sqlite3
According to [this](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html), renaming a column is possible.

Comment: IIRC, renaming columns was added in 3.25. If you're using an older version you have to do it the long way.

Comment: @Shawn  See  https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html.  It looks to me like there was only a change to renaming tables in 3.25 and 3.26.  There is no particular note about renaming columns.  Now I see this is the same link as in the question.

Comment: @CPerkins Yup, it was 3.25 that added that feature. https://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_25_0.html

Comment: Get and post more detail about the error.  See https://sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html.  "Failed" is usually insufficient when debugging, especially when posting on Stack Overflow and asking others for help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891190/sqlite3-stepstatement-sqlite-done-is-always-false